# Find and remove Element from structured list c#

Tags: c#, list, data-structures

Good Morning,
I have a list of person

```
private List<Person> person = new List<Person>();
```

Person is a class

```
public class Person
{
    public double trackID; 
    int Age;
}
```

I would like remove the item that have a particular ID (ID2 in the code).
How can i do?

i try this but i have some error exceptions:

```
foreach (Person p in person)
{
   if (p.ID == ID2)
   {
     person.Remove(p);
   }
}
```

thank you in advance for your cooperation

Comment: You won't be able to remove items from the list while iterating over it (e.g. [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4536090/1364007)). You can instead use use the [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803) method: `person.Where(p => p.ID != ID2)`.

Comment: Also, a stylistic issue, but it's a bit confusing to have a collection named in the singular. It'd be less confusing to call it `persons` or `people`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linq as show below:

```
var person.RemoveAll(x => x.ID == ID2);
```